# Какой второй коммутатор выбрать?

Tags: hp

Товарищи сисадмины, помогайте. Стоит у меня шлюз на Centos с двумя сетевками - одна внешка, другая локалка. В локалку шнурок идёт на управляемый коммутатор (от которого правда пароль был успешно забыт) HP ProCurve 1810G-24 ([Такой](http://market.yandex.ru/model.xml?hid=91088&modelid=4980449)). Но 24 порта перестало хватать и решил я поставить второй коммутатор, уже неуправляемый, тоже L2, как и первый. И вот сижу и думаю про всякие совместимости и т.п. - не хватает у меня немного опыта и знаний в этом.
Выбрал я [вот такой](http://www.nix.ru/autocatalog/networking_3com/hp_141024G_J9561A_24UTP_1000_2Combo_1000BASET_SFP_145901.html) коммутатор, но не уверен на все 100%, нормально ли он встанет с первым (коммутаторы я хочу просто шнурком один к другому ткнуть и всё, остальные шнурки на машины из обоих свичей, так же нормально?). Вообще бюджет в районе 19 тыс. примерно, если есть предложения, скажите (желательно конечно тоже HP), но по характеристикам и вот этот 1410-24G меня устраивает.
Короче если возьму 1410 и просто кабелем подключу его к 1810, то нормально же всё будет работать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы просто, да, ответил, но символов не хватает. А так, да.

Comment: Сейчас посмотрел, оказывается тупо ссылки сделал (исправил сейчас), но так понимаю, что Вы разбираетесь и без них:) Так что благодарю.